# Django default of ArrayField is a callable, but I still get a warning?

Tags: python, django

so I've got this model:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    d_changes = ArrayField(models.FloatField(), default=list(), verbose_name='D Changes')
    w_changes = ArrayField(models.FloatField(), default=list(), verbose_name='A Changes')
```

And when I want to create a migration or a fixture I always receive the following warning for both fields:

```
backend.Action.d_changes: (postgres.E003) ArrayField default should be a callable instead of an instance so that it's not shared between all field instances.
    HINT: Use a callable instead, e.g., use `list` instead of `[]`.
```

For my migrations its not such a big deal, since everything still works fine. But when I try to create a fixture of my db, my .json File always ends up with this bit in the very top of my .json file:

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
[33;1mbackend.Action.d_changes: (postgres.E003) ArrayField default should be a callable instead of an instance so that it's not shared between all field instances.
    HINT: Use a callable instead, e.g., use `list` instead of `[]`.[0m
[33;1mbackend.Action.w_changes: (postgres.E003) ArrayField default should be a callable instead of an instance so that it's not shared between all field instances.
    HINT: Use a callable instead, e.g., use `list` instead of `[]`.[0m
```

Which breaks my .json file and thus I cannot use loaddata, as I always receive a DeserializationError(), so I have to manually remove that part.

So what exactly is wrong with the model fields? I mean I'm literally using `default=list()` which is a callable?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Remove the `()` as `list()` will return an empty list. You want to be writing `default=list`

Comment: "list()" is a call to create a list (which is not callable). You may want "list" without parentheses.

Comment: The value of `list()` is not a callable, the value of `list` is a callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this:

```py
class Action(models.Model):
    d_changes = ArrayField(models.FloatField(), default=list, verbose_name='D Changes')
    w_changes = ArrayField(models.FloatField(), default=list, verbose_name='A Changes')
```

`list()` is not callable `list` is callable. because `list()` has been already called.